# Regex limit specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex allowing only mandarin(Chinese) chars, digits and some special chars

`/^[[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF0-9.,\- '/(/)]+$/`

Now I need change it and allow up to 10 instances of any latin char[a-zA-Z], but now more than 10. Is it a way to do it with a regex?

Comment: Do you want to allow 10 specific latin chars e.g. a,b,c .. or x, or allow 10 instances of any latin (a-z) char?

Comment: Good, so, what is not working for you?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. What 10 characters of latin? First 10 in alphabet, first 10 chars? You gotta be specific with these sort of questions... Also I got a feeling, if you have a basic understanding of regex (around 5 minutes of tutorial reading), you have an answer for this already

Comment: Yes, I want to allow 10 instances of any latin char

Comment: Use `/^(?!(?:[^A-Za-z]*[a-zA-Z]){11})[A-Za-z\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF0-9., '()-]+$/`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor

Answer (score 0):

/^(?!(?:[^A-Za-z]*[a-zA-Z]){11})[A-Za-z\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF0-9., '()-]+$/